# how to make Image from area map coordinates

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple area map on an image.What I want to do is to make images from those areas.How can I do that?
 the shapes are poly
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried with an example? And describe with that what does not work for you. (Am I right you want kind of screen capture? What should be the colour for the areas outside of the map areas (assuming you want rectangular images, with non-rectangular map areas)?)

Comment: Client-side and server-side solutions exist. Depends what you want to do with the resulting images.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos .The color is not important.I just want to extract that area from image and make another image with that content.The shape are poly

Comment: HTML5  Canvas (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp)

Comment: You'll need to explain the context better. As it stands the answer is probably to start `MS Paint` or `Photoshop` and erase the areas outside the polygons and save as JPEG.